# Run Docker, Execute Command, Exit

Tags: docker

I am trying to run tests in docker as part of my build process. What i'd like to do is start the docker container, ignore the normal entry point, run a test command, and immediately exit with the test status.

Something like:

```
results=`docker run my_image --entrypoint python -m unittest discover`
```

When I try this I get: `entrypoint requires the handler name to be the first argument`

- Which I believe is a specific to the image I am building off of (aws lambda).

So far I'm only seeing options to each A) start the container and issue an arbitrary command, or  B) have a second Dockerfile just for testing.

Is it possible to run a docker image with an arbitrary command (ignoring the default entrypoint) where after the command is executed the container is killed?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should restructure your application to avoid needing to override the entrypoint.

Remember that, when you run an image, [the `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` are combined to form a single command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact).  If you'll frequently be replacing this (combined) command string, it's best to put the whole command into `CMD`.  If you have `ENTRYPOINT` at all, it should be a wrapper that runs the command passed to it as arguments (in a shell script, with `exec "$@"`).

```sh
# Optional entrypoint -- MUST be JSON-array syntax, and MUST `exec "$@"`
# ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD python ... whatever you had before
```

Then once you do this, you can easily override the command part at the `docker run` command

```sh
docker run my_image python -m unittest discover
```

(There are two other `ENTRYPOINT` patterns I've seen.  One is a "container as command" pattern, where the entire command line is in `ENTRYPOINT`, and the command part is used to take additional arguments; this supports a `docker run imagename --extra-args` pattern.  If you really need this pattern, see below to override the whole thing.  The second arbitrarily splits `ENTRYPOINT ["python"]`, `CMD ["script.py"]`, but there's no particular reason to do this; just combine them into `CMD`.)

If you can't refactor your image's Dockerfile, then you need to override `--entrypoint`.  This option only takes a single command word, though, and it's treated as a Docker option so it needs to come *before* the image name.  That leads to this awkward construction (split into multiple lines for readability):

```sh
docker run \
  --entrypoint python \
  my_image \
  -m unittest discover
```

Also consider the possibilities of using a non-Docker host virtual environment for routine tasks like running your service's unit tests.